# Drupal + Lighttpd: enabling clean urls (rewriting)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, lighttpd

I'm emulating Ubuntu on my mac, and I use it as a server.

I've installed lighttpd + Drupal and the following configuration section requires a domain name in order to make clean urls to work.

Since I'm using a local server I don't have a domain name and I was wondering how to make it work given the fact the ip of the local machine is usually changing.

thanks

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mywebsite\.com" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/sites/mywebsite"
  server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/error.log"
  server.name = "mywebsite.com"
  accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/mywebsite/access.log"
  include_shell "./drupal-lua-conf.sh mywebsite.com"

  url.access-deny += ( "~", ".inc", ".engine", ".install", ".info",
       ".module", ".sh", "sql", ".theme",
       ".tpl.php", ".xtmpl", "Entries",
       "Repository", "Root" )


  # "Fix" for Drupal SA-2006-006, requires lighttpd 1.4.13 or above
  # Only serve .php files of the drupal base directory
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/.*/.*\.php$" {
      fastcgi.server = ()
      url.access-deny = ("")
  }

  magnet.attract-physical-path-to = ("/etc/lighttpd/drupal-lua-scripts/p-.lua")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use localhost as the hostname. localhost points to 127.0.0.1 which is your local server. Assuming lighttpd is configured to listen on every interface that should work.

Just try http://localhost/ and see what happens.

if you need to configure your site in a subdirectory of your web root dir, something like http://localhost/site1/ and you want to access that from a single domain like site1.localhost you can always add that to the hosts file (/etc/hosts):

`127.0.0.1        site1.localhost`

And configure lighttpd appropriately.

Comment: I've tested with Firefox inside the emulated Ubuntu and it works. How can I set localhost in MAC OSX pointing Ubuntu Lighttpd server ? Do I need to enable apache in MACOSX to forward it, or I can change network settings ? thanks

Comment: That's a bit more tricky. The emulated ubuntu (how are you emulating it?) should have it's own local IP address that communicates with the Host OS (Mac). So you have to find what that IP address it, and use that to access it the emulated ubuntu from your MAC. YOu can then edit the hosts file (or whatever the method is for MAC) to make that IP be a domain name, like: "ubuntu", but there's no need for that, IP only should work.